# How to write a method to delete some lines in a file with a flask request?

Tags: python, flask

I must write a method to delete some lines in a txt file. The lines are defined by the request in the flask route. I don't find how to do....
For now, it deletes everything in the file.

I wrote that:

```
class Book:
    
    #properties
    def __init__(self, title, author, genre, comment, ):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.genre = genre
        self.comment = comment
        self.identity = id(self)

    ##methods
    #write info book in db.txt
    def write_info_book(self, file):   
    
        file = open("booksdb.txt", "a")
        file.write("Title: " +self.title +"\n")
        file.write("\t" + "Author: " + self.author + "\n")
        file.write("\t"+ "Genre: " + self.genre + "\n")
        file.write("\t"+ "Your comment: " + self.comment + "\n")
        file.write("---" + "\n")
        file.close()
    
    #delete a book in txt file
    def delete_book_txt(self, file):
        
        file = open("booksdb.txt", "r")
        content = file.read()
        file.close()
        file = open("booksdb.txt", "w")
        books = content.split("---")
        books = get_books_to_delete()
        title = flask.request.args.get("b")
        for book in books:
            if book.lower().find(title.lower()) != -1:
                file.write(books)
```

And the route:

```
@app.route("/delete")
def delete():
    title = flask.request.args.get("b") 
    html_page =get_html("delete")
    
    Book.delete_book_txt( file= "booksdb.txt")
    if title == None or title == "":
        return html_page.replace("$$DELETE$$", "You didn't enter any book to delete")
    else:
        return html_page.replace("$$DELETE$$", title)
```

I really don't understand how i should do.... I really hope someone can help me, because whatever I try, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You're not thinking about what you have.  `content` is the entire file.  `books` is a list of individual books, but then you immediately throw that away, and replace it with your list of books to delete.

And why do you pass the file name as a parameter (called "file"), and then immediately reuse that name by opening a hardcoded file name?  You're not thinking about what data you have and what data you need.

There are two ways to delete lines from a file.  (1) open both files,  for each line in the old file, if you want to keep the line write it, else don't write it.  (2) Open first file, read lines into a list, manipulate the list (adding, replacing), join the lines using your separator, write the joined list to file.

So:

```
    def delete_book_txt(self, file):
        books = open(file, "r").split('---')
        newbooks = []
        title = flask.request.args.get("b")
        for book in books:
            if title.lower() not in book.lower():
                newbooks.append(book)
        open(file,"w").write('---'.join(newbooks))
```

In the long term, of course, the right answer is to use a database.  SQLite is built-in to Python, and would be a perfectly good way to store your books.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I really still have some problems to understand at what moment i use and need what... I will make it with what you wrote. And yes, for the future I will learn how to do with SQlite, but i must use this way for this exercice

Comment: I don't know how to thank you enough.... was trying since one week....and you solved and helped me in 5 minutes and made things very clear and understandable.

Comment: I am sorry.. it brings me another question... when i enter nothing for the request, it shows the "You didn't enter any book to delete" as expected...and when I go back to the books page, it deletes all... it is my if..else which is wrong?? ```if title == None or title == "":
        return html_page.replace("$$DELETE$$", "You didn't enter any book to delete")
    else:
        return html_page.replace("$$DELETE$$", title)```

Comment: Since you don't want to change ANYTHING when there's no title, clearly the call to `delete_book_txt` should be in the `else` clause, not before you check the value.